# GreenDAO QueryBuilder dynamically concatenate conditions

Tags: android, sqlite, greendao

I need to verify some conditions to create a complete query:

```
QueryBuilder<MyObj> qb = getMyObjDao().queryBuilder();

if ( someCondition )
     qb.where(MyObjDao.Properties.Prop1.eq(someValue));
else       
    qb.whereOr(MyObjDao.Properties.Prop2.eq(someValue),MyObjDao.Properties.Prop2.eq(someValue));

if ( someOtherCondition )
     qb.where(MyObjDao.Properties.Prop3.eq(someValue));
else
     qb.whereOr(MyObjDao.Properties.Prop4.eq(someValue));
```

So is it possible to concatenate query builder conditions and create query builder dynamically?

Answer (score 0):

In general, it's possible to create dynamic queries using QueryBuilder.

Does this already answer your question? If you have issues, please be more specific.